# Error: Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data. --> What does that mean?

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest, prediction, shinydashboard

I am trying to map prediction results in the Shiny app. In this context, the users should be provided with different input masks. If a user enters e.g. Adults = 2, children = 1, previous_cancellations = 0 etc., then the Shiny App should output in percent how likely it is that a cancellation will happen under the given conditions.

Unfortunately, I get two errors displayed:

1. type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
2. object of type 'closure' is not indexable.

Can someone please help me to solve both errors?

This is the code:

````
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)
library(RCurl)
library(randomForest)
library(flexdashboard)

hotel <- structure(
  list(
    hotel = c(
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel"), 
    is_canceled = c(0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    adults = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
               2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    children = c(0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    babies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
               1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    meal = c("BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "FB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "HB", 
             "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
             "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "HB"), 
    is_repeated_guest = c(
      0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0
    ), 
    previous_cancellations = c(
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0
    ), 
    previous_bookings_not_canceled = c(
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      1
    ), 
    reserved_room_type = c(
      "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", 
      "C", "A", "D", "E", "D", "D", "G", "E", "D", "E", "A", "A", "G", 
      "F", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "A", "D", "A", "D", "E", 
      "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "E", "G", "D", "F", "E", "A", "G", 
      "A", "B", "A", "E"
    ), 
    deposit_type = c(
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "Test", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "Test", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit"
    ), 
    customer_type = c(
      "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Contract", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient-Party", "Contract", "Transient"
    ), 
    adr = c(
      0, 
      0, 75, 75, 98, 98, 107, 103, 82, 105, 123, 145, 97, 154, 94, 
      97, 97, 88, 107, 153, 97, 84, 84, 99, 94, 63, 79, 107, 94, 87, 
      62, 63, 108, 65, 108, 108, 98, 108, 108, 137, 117, 79, 123, 137, 
      110, 153, 58, 82, 82, 119
    ), 
    total_of_special_requests = c(
      0, 
      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
      1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
      1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1
    )
  ), 
  row.names = c(NA, -50L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", 
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

hotel$is_canceled <- as.factor(hotel$is_canceled)
hotel$is_repeated_guest <- as.factor(hotel$is_repeated_guest)
hotel$meal <- as.factor(hotel$meal)
hotel$reserved_room_type <- as.factor(hotel$reserved_room_type)
hotel$deposit_type <- as.factor(hotel$deposit_type)
hotel$customer_type <- as.factor(hotel$customer_type)
hotel$adr <- as.integer(hotel$adr)
hotel$hotel <- as.factor(hotel$hotel)


library(dplyr)


model_rf <- randomForest::randomForest(is_canceled ~., data = hotel, ntree = 100, mtry = 5, importance = TRUE)


ui <- fluidPage(headerPanel('HotelCancellationPrediction'),
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput('hotel', label = 'Hotel',
                              c('City Hotel','Resort Hotel')),
                  sliderInput('adults', label = 'Erwachsene',
                              min=1, max=3, value=1),
                  sliderInput('children', label = 'Kinder',
                              min=0, max =2, value = 0),
                  sliderInput('babies', label = 'Kinder',
                              min = 0, max=3, value = 0),
                  selectInput('meal', label = 'Mahlzeit',
                              c('HB','BB')),
                  sliderInput('is_repeated_guest', label='Erneuter Gast',
                              min = 0, max = 1, value = 0),
                  sliderInput('previous_cancellations', label='Vorherige Stornierungen',
                              min = 0, max = 1, value = 0),
                  sliderInput('previous_bookings_not_canceled', label = 'vorherige Bookings not cancelled',
                              min = 0, max = 1, value = 0),
                  selectInput('reserved_room_type', label = 'Raumtyp',
                              c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')),
                  selectInput('deposit_type', label='Bezahltyp',
                              c('No Deposit','Test')),
                  selectInput('customer_type', label = 'Kundentyp',
                              c('Transient','Transient-Party','Contract')),
                  sliderInput('adr', label = 'Kosten',
                              min=0, max=200, value=0),
                  sliderInput('total_of_special_requests', label='Sonderwuensche',
                              min=0, max=2, value=0),
                  submitButton('Submit')
                  
                ),
                
                mainPanel(
                  tags$label(h3('Status/Output')),
                  verbatimTextOutput('contents'),
                  tableOutput('tabledata'),
                  gaugeOutput('Scale')
                )
                
                )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  datasetInput <-  reactive({
    df <-  data.frame(
      Name = c('hotel',
               'adults',
               'children',
               'babies',
               'meal',
               'is_repeated_guest',
               'previous_cancellations',
               'previous_bookings_not_canceled',
               'reserved_room_type',
               'deposit_type',
               'customer_type',
               'adr',
               'total_of_special_requests'),
      value = as.character(c(input$hotel,
                             input$adults,
                             input$children,
                             input$babies,
                             input$meal,
                             input$is_repeated_guest,
                             input$previous_cancellations,
                             input$previous_bookings_not_canceled,
                             input$reserved_room_type,
                             input$deposit_type,
                             input$customer_type,
                             input$adr,
                             input$total_of_special_requests)),
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    
    is_canceled <- 'is_canceled'
  
    df <- rbind(df, is_canceled)
    input <- transpose(df)
    write.table(input, 'input.csv', sep =',', quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    write.table(input,"input4.csv", sep = ',', quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
    
    test <- read.csv(paste("input", ".csv", sep=""), header = TRUE)
    test$hotel <- factor(test$hotel, levels=c("City Hotel","Resort Hotel"))
    test$meal <- factor(test$meal, levels = c('HB','BB'))
    test$reserved_room_type <- factor(test$reserved_room_type, levels = c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'))
    test$deposit_type <- factor(test$deposit_type, levels = c('No Deposit','Test'))
    test$customer_type <- factor(test$customer_type, levels = c('Transient','Transient-Party','Contract'))
    
    
    
    Output <- data.frame(Prediction = predict(model_rf, test), round(predict(model_rf, test, type='prob'),3))
    print(Output)
  })
  
  my_plot <-  reactive({
    gauge(datasetInput()$Yes, min=0, max=100, symbol='%', label='Success', gaugeSectors(
      success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0,39)))
  })
  output$Scale <- renderGauge({
    my_plot
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderPrint({
    "forecast Results"
  })
  
  output$tabledata <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)```
````

Comment: The first error is caused by not performing a stratified sampling of your data set.  When training, every factor and combination of factors need to be in your training set.  Most likely your training set missed having a particular hotel type or customer_type.  For your limited dataset and large number of variables/values it is better to train on the full data set and find another technique to test. (maybe bootstrapping it?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help and recommendations. By this dataset I only wanted to give an example to understand better, what I mean. Actually I am using a large data set. I have now adjusted the data set a bit so that error NR. 1 does not appear anymore. However, the second error is still there: object of type 'closure' is not indexable. Do you have any idea what this could mean and where the error is in the code? I will paste the new code again.

Comment: Please don’t post updates as a separate answer but instead edit your question.  Also please run your code line by line to identify the source of the second error.